# Adding text in a circle border

Tags: html, css

The following code below adds a radio button with a number inside a border, but the border should be circle, how can I make it circle?

Note that the position of the text is important to not be affected by the css.

```css
 
 p {
 outline-style: solid;
 padding : 16px;
     position: absolute;

 }
```

```html
<p><input type="radio">1</p>
```

Comment: Just use `border: 3px solid black; border-radius: 50%;` instead of `outline-style: solid;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) and [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) properties instead of `outline-style`:

```css
 p {
   border: 3px solid #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 45px;  
   line-height: 45px;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   width: 45px;
 }
```

```html
<p><input type="radio">1</p>
```

As you can see, you may also need to change the height and width elements to ensure that the element is a perfect circle (well, square).

Comment: Looks more like an oval than a circle

Comment: @j08691 Was editing the question when you added your comment...

Comment: I don't want the text to change position. It is really important to keep the exact position

Comment: Then don’t change the text-align or line-height properties then.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the border and then use order-radius.

```css
p {
border: solid 2px black;
     padding : 16px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     }
```

```html
<p><input type="radio">1</p>
```